# How to imports reports from local server to report viewer form in visual studio

Tags: c#

I created some reports by using SQL SERVER data tools. Then I upload the reports into windows 2012 server. there they are executing properly.But when I try to import them into my visual studio report viewer its not executing anything. I tried following code. Can you please tell if any another procedure available? or what credentials do I need to give for ? please help me I am unable to find the solution from couple of days

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                reportViewer1.ProcessingMode =
     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;

                reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = 
    @"/Adventureworks Sample Reports/Company Sales";

                NetworkCredential myCred = new 
    NetworkCredential(<UserName>, <Password>, <DomainName>);
                reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials =
           myCred;

                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
```

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten to specify `ReportServerUrl`?

Comment: I tried that one too. but its showing me rsltem not found. but I gave the correct file name

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my quetion. Here is the answer.

reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = 
    @"/Adventureworks Sample Reports/Company Sales";-------------> there is no need to mention the "Adventureworks Sample Reports".

we can write directly like

reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = 
    @"/Company Sales";